# DAX LOOKUPVALUE to return "Undefined" instead of blank?

Tags: powerbi, dax, lookup-tables

How to get an alternative result string message "Not found" or "Undefined", if the LOOKUPVALUE function does not find a match? The documentation of the [LOOKUPVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/lookupvalue-function-dax) function mentions it is easily possible by using the fourth parameter. The fourth parameter is optional. But when I type it, I receive an error message.

Here is why I need it. I want a Category of a product which has not been defined in a dictionary yet. It might be a classic scenerio. The dictionary table is updated manually with some lag and thus it does not contain all the unique products which pop up in FactTable. I want to solve it by Bridge table which will automate manual feeding of Dictionary.

[image]

I use the following **Bridge** table.

```
Bridge = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        DISTINCT(UNION(DISTINCT(FactTable[product]), DISTINCT(Dictionary[product])))
        , "FoundCategory"
        , LOOKUPVALUE(
              Dictionary[category]
            , Dictionary[product]
            , FactTable[product]
            --, "Undefined" -- Uncommenting this argument throws error
    )
)
```

**Edit. After 2019 update of Power BI, this problem perished. It must have been a sort of a bug. The above code is working. Hurray!**

How to force LOOKUPVALUE function to return `Undefined` string value instead of `blank()`?

I can think of this:

```
Bridge = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    DISTINCT(UNION(DISTINCT(FactTable[product]), DISTINCT(Dictionary[product])))
    , "FoundCategory"
    , IF(ISBLANK(
        LOOKUPVALUE(
          Dictionary[category]
        , Dictionary[product]
        , FactTable[product])
        )
        ,"Unmapped"
        ,LOOKUPVALUE(
          Dictionary[category]
        , Dictionary[product]
        , FactTable[product])
        )
)
```

However I wonder if it does not calculate the LOOKUPVALUE twice. If so, what might be more efficient way?

Here are the tables if you would like to recreate the problem.

**FactTable:**

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSiwoyElVitWJVkpKzANCMLMgvySxJF8pNhYA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [product = _t])
in
    Source
```

**Dictionary:**

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSiwoyElV0lFKKyrNLFGK1YlWKsgvSSzJBwqVpaanliQmAaVjYwE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [product = _t, category = _t])
in
    Source
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other way to do this is to use the LOOKUPVALUE functions alternative value field.  This allows you to specify a value returned instead of blank, thus saving having to do a check to see if it is blank.

[LOOKUPVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/lookupvalue-function-dax) in Microsoft's online documentation on the function.

Edit: 
Did a quick test in Power BI Desktop and was able to get alternate values to work in a calculated column to an existing model.

```
LOOKUPVALUE(
          Dictionary[category]
        , Dictionary[product]
        , FactTable[product])
        , "Undefined"
)
```

Comment: I tried but I could not get it to work. The function does not accept the fourth parameter. If you sure it works, can you please edit my code to get it working?

Comment: I think, Power BI DAX no longer supports AlternateResult for LOOKUPVALUE function. Something to read here from March 2019 :- https://community.powerbi.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/LOOKUPVALUE-doesn-t-seem-to-work-with-Alternate-Results/td-p/684831

Comment: Very interesting. I cannot get it to work. Do you make a DAX table of your code, measure or calculated column? Can you paste the full code of DAX table, the one I named Bridge. Have you got it to work with Power BI or Excel?

Comment: I think my problem with LOOKUPVALUE must have been some kind of a bug. After the 2019 July PBI update, it works smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an if else loop inside that with something like this :-

```
Bridge = 
    ADDCOLUMNS
   (
    DISTINCT(UNION(DISTINCT(FactTable[product]), DISTINCT(Dictionary[product]))),
    "FoundCategory",
    IF(
          LOOKUPVALUE(
          Dictionary[category],
          Dictionary[product],
          FactTable[product]) = "", 
          "Undefined", 
          LOOKUPVALUE(
          Dictionary[category],
          Dictionary[product],
          FactTable[product]))
    )
```

Or you could do something like this,

```
Bridge = 
        DISTINCT(UNION(DISTINCT(FactTable[product]), DISTINCT(Dictionary[product])))
```

Then a calculated column:-

```
foundCategory = 

var look_up_value = LOOKUPVALUE(
          Dictionary[category],
          Dictionary[product],
          Bridge[product])

var out = IF(look_up_value = BLANK(), "undefined", look_up_value)

return out
```

Comment: Thank you. I just cook similar solution up and edited it to my question. I used BLANK instead of "". I wonder about the performance of that solution. Seems to be calculating it twice.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin I get what you are saying, it will be interesting to solve it with Var concept. Will wait and see, if anyone brings a easy solution.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin Edited my answer again, may be that might help.

Comment: Looks marvelous!

Comment: I'd like to leave it open for a day or two just in case someone shares a different approach or adds a comment to your answer. Sure, your answer looks promising candidate for accepted answer.